# How to modify linux console prompt line ( for a while )

Tags: linux, console

For example I typed such commands:

```
user@my-machine:~$ cd ABC
user@my-machine:~/ABC$ cd long-name
user@my-machine:~/ABC/long-name$ cd another-long-name
user@my-machine:~/ABC/long-name/another-long-name$ ls
```

So, I've chosen directory I need, and I need to work in it ( lots of commands ). But half of my console line is the prompt line. It's not very comfortable. Can I shorten it for a while? For example I'll make it `user@my-machine:~foo$` and when I finish working in this directory - I'll turn this shortness off.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In the future, this is a very superuser.com post, not stackoverflow question.

Comment: Ok, I understand, next time I won't make this mistake ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prompt format is in the `PS1` environment variable; see the `bash` manpage, `prompting` section for format specifiers.

```
10:50:39 user@host:1996 ~$ echo $PS1
\t \u@\h:\! \W$
```

The `\W` only prints the top directory like you (?) want. (`\w` prints the whole thing like you have now).

```
10:50:45 user@host:1997 ~$ PS1='\u@\h:\W$ '
user@host:~$ cd test
user@host:test$ cd testdir/
user@host:testdir$
```

You'll probably want to save the old `PS1` in a variable (say, `$ export OLDPS1=$PS1`) first so you can restore it when you're done (`$ PS1=$OLDPS1`).

Comment: Yeap: ` export OLDPS1=$PS1` and `PS1='\u@\h:\W$` is what I needed

Answer (score 4):

I just put the prompt on a second line, and the user/directory information is put on the first.

Example of my bash prompt:

```
birryree@momohime:/usr/bin
$ command-here
```

If you're using bourne-shell or bash, the environment variable `PS1` determines the formatting of the prompt.

I have this in my `~/.bash_profile` (you might use `.bashrc`, I have my `.bashrc` source my `.bash_profile`).

```
# ~/.bash_profile
PS1="\u@\h:\w\n$ " # \u means user name
                   # \h means hostname
                   # \w is working directory
                   # \n is newline
                   # $ is my prompt
```

And my `.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_profile
```

For fun, my zsh prompt looks like this:

```
birryree@momohime:~/.oh-my-zsh master* 
λ >
```

The `master*` means I'm on the master branch of a git repository (`~/.oh-my-zsh` is a git-controlled directory), and the directory is unclean.

---

You can get extremely fancy with your bash prompts, I used to do colors and everything before I switched to zsh.

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt

This section has all the escapes:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Prompt_escapes